# Publishing papers with two different surnames

Tags: publications

I am dual nationality. My surname on my both passports is totally different in terms of writing. Because some leters in country A has different writing style in country B. I already has determined my both surnames on my all academic platforms.

Is it possible to publish papers sometimes with surname A and sometimes with surname B according to the situation?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to publish under two different names, but in any case, an ORCID indentifier helps you to tie both names together.

Comment: I'm curious, is this a case of something like Górski/Gorski or Brishnapervanandry/Smith, or something else completely? (No, I'm not asking you to actually identify yourself?)

Comment: Or it could be something like Chebyshev / Чебышёв .  The OP said "different writing style".

Comment: Your dual nationality and how your name is written in your passports is entirely irrelevant. There is no obligation to use your precise legal name when publishing research.

Comment: Actually it is something like (Jalal/ Celaloglu ) both names have the same meaning but the writing style is different. (J) is equivalent to (C). @CGCampbell

Comment: I am currently working in country A registered with surname A . When I want to work in country B I will be registered with a passport with the surname B, then I should publish papers with country B's surname. This is the issue. @Sursula

Comment: What does working in a country have to do with the name you publish under? You publish under whatever name you publish under. I'm not sure I understand. Are they going to deport you for using the wrong spelling?

Comment: As a librarian; if you do this then please get an ORCID ID https://orcid.org

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really anything that would force you to pick the same name anytime you publish something. In some cases, this may require you to have separate accounts with the journal/publisher to keep the meta data separate. Other than that, you just enter whatever name suits you right now in the name field, and that's it.

However, this seems like a **very ill-advised plan** to me. Even if you use OrcID or so to link your identities back together, you'd still lose out on the name recognition. Much of the process of building an academic career is tied to us developing a personal brand, which pretty means using the same academic name for all of our endeavours.

Comment: The joys of English spelling and homophones (or near homophones)...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to record or list your publications under your researcher ID, such as in Orcid. Hence, you can synchronize them with other scientific websites, such as Scopus, etc.
In addition, you have to add your papers to Google Scholar.
In this case, you will not lose your index from your publications due to the name differences.

Best Regards

Comment: In general the association between individuals and their work is a lot less formal than ORCID. Sure, if you're in one of the places that counts papers and quartiles/impact factors for hiring/promotion (terrible policy, seems to be the encouraging feature behind a lot of research fraud and paper mill-type situations) and you need to document your "score", it's fine, but for your actual reputation among academics, that comes from people reading your work or seeing you talk at a conference and eventually putting your name together with a conceptual idea of your work. Orcid doesn't help there.